# Why wont my Android app automatically run from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run my app in debug mode on an Android device from Android Studio. I press the Debug 'app' button and it goes through the build process and then it says "Launch succeeded" in a bubble above the Debug tab, but the app doesn't start running. If I press the Debug button again though it does start and it says "App restart successful without requiring a re-install" in a bubble above the Run tab. Why won't it start the first time? I have "Launch" set to "Default Activity" under the Launch Options. Is there anything else I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: Check the logs and make sure it's not crashing for some reason, if it happens early you won't see the app start at all

Comment: Its because your adb runs on a busy port. Try killing adb service and run it again on another port.

Comment: It's definitely not crashing. It happens every time. If I just press the debug button again it works.